# swapping elements in list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of 2 elements having randomly colored containers. I want to swap the first and second element. the code is

```
tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));
```

It's working fine, swapping colors with each other all the time, but I can't figure out what is happening there. Can someone please explain what is going on?

full code: (obtained from https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d)

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: PositionedTiles()));

class PositionedTiles extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PositionedTilesState();
}

class PositionedTilesState extends State<PositionedTiles> {
 List<Widget> tiles = [
   StatelessColorfulTile(),
   StatelessColorfulTile(),
 ];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Row(children: tiles),
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
         child: Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied), onPressed: swapTiles),
   );
 }

 swapTiles() {
   setState(() {
     tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));
   });
 }
}

class StatelessColorfulTile extends StatelessWidget {
 Color myColor = UniqueColorGenerator.getColor();
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
       color: myColor, child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(70.0)));
 }
}
```

Comment: You mean you can't understand what `tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));` is doing?

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad yes. i dont get how it swaps the elements.

Comment: Note that `tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0))` is very inefficient since it involves moving almost all of the list elements down one position and then back.  `var tempElement = tiles[0]; tiles[0] = tiles[1]; tiles[1] = tempElement;` would be much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> tiles.insert(1, tiles.removeAt(0));

```
index:       0        1
tiles:     [ tileOne, tileTwo ]
```

1. It removes the tile at index 0 which shifts the remaining elements down 1 to fill the space.

```
index:       0
tiles:     [ tileTwo ]
removed: tileOne
```

2. It inserts the tile at index 1.

```
index:       0        1
tiles:     [ tileTwo, tileOne ]
```

Comment: but isn't it creating a new tile at 1?... if so, then how does it shows the color alternating effect since the newly created tile should have a random color?

Comment: ok...got it. i thought flutter is deleting the tile and adding a whole new tile by that code. I didn't know that flutter could carry that removed tile till it could execute the insert function  :)

Comment: I'm happy that helped. `removeAt` does return the same object that it removes.

Comment: tiles.removeAt(0) return tileOne at first, then insert it to position 1

Answer (score 10):

For those coming here based on the question title, here is how you could swap elements in a Dart list:

```dart
int firstIndex = 0;
int secondIndex = 3;
final myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
final temp = myList[firstIndex];
myList[firstIndex] = myList[secondIndex];
myList[secondIndex] = temp;

// [d, b, c, a, e]
```

Or implementing that in an extension:

```dart
extension SwappableList<E> on List<E> {
  void swap(int first, int second) {
    final temp = this[first];
    this[first] = this[second];
    this[second] = temp;
  }
}
```

would allow you to use it like so:

```dart
final myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
myList.swap(0, 3); 

// [d, b, c, a, e]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays we can do:

```
yourList.swap(index0, index1)
```

This has been added to the 'collection' package as per collection v1.18.0

Here the source location: https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/blob/master/lib/src/list_extensions.dart#L221

Here the commit:
https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/commit/7d44763d62f97698b15c08ee360d838dccb63c88